# Find the time taken by B to fill it given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A, B and C are $3$ taps connected to a tank.The time taken by C to fill the tank is $9$/$2$ times the time taken by A and B to fill it.The time taken by A to fill the tank is $5$/$6$ times the time taken by B and C to fill it.A,B and C take $20$/$11$ hours to fill it.Find the time taken by B to fill it?

options:

a)$10$/$3$  b)$5$ c) $20$/$3$ d)$10$

Myapproach:

C=$9$/$2$ . (A+B)

A=$5$/$6$ . (B+C)

A+B+C=$11$/$20$

I solved these equations and i am getting nowhere close to the results.

> Is my approach right?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Are you assuming that A, B, C are the times it takes taps A, B, C respectively, to fill up the tank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a, b, c$ be the respective flow rates of taps A, B, C. 
Let $t_1, t_2, t_3$ be the respective times taken for single taps A, B, C to fill the tank.

Hence, volume of tank is given by:

$$at_1=bt_2=ct_3=\frac 29 (a+b)t_3=\frac 65 (b+c)t_1=\frac{20}{11}(a+b+c)\\
\Rightarrow a+b=\frac 92 c;\qquad b+c=\frac 56 a\\
\Rightarrow \frac ab=2;\qquad \frac cb=\frac 23\\
\Rightarrow t_2=\frac {20}{11}\left(\frac ab+\frac cb+1\right)=\frac {20}3\qquad\blacksquare$$